# The Properties.load would close the InputStream?

Tags: java, properties, inputstream, java-io

I saw [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/properties_load_stream.htm), and I didn't see the `close()` method invoked on the `InputStream`, so would `prop.load()` close the stream automatically? Or is there a bug in the example?

Comment: I just checked the java code for load(stream) and it doesn't close the stream.

Comment: Bug in the example. `Properties.load()` doesn't close the stream. You have to do that. Very poor quality example all round.  It wouldn't even work on some operating systems. Don't rely on arbitrary Internet junk. Use the Oracle Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stream is not closed after Properties.load ()

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("abc.properties"));

    new Properties().load(in);

    System.out.println(in.read());
}
```

The above code returns "-1" so the stream is not closed. Otherwise it should have thrown `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`

Answer (score 4):

Why do you ask when the javadoc of [`Properties.load(InputStream inStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) says this?

> The specified stream **remains open** after this method returns.

It has been saying that since Java 6.

As EJP said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078141/the-properties-load-would-close-the-inputstream/40078397#comment67429310_40078141): *Don't rely on arbitrary Internet junk.* Use the official Oracle Java documentation as your primary source of information.

Answer (score 1):

The following *try-with-resources* will close the `InputStream` automatically (you can add `catch` and `finally` if needed):

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("properties.txt")) {
    // is will be closed automatically
}
```

---

> Any resource declared within a try block opening will be closed. Hence, the new construct shields you from having to pair try blocks with corresponding finally blocks that are dedicated to proper resource management.

Article by Oracle here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html.